# Digital audio gain past 100% for my computer mic? (win XP)

Tags: microphone, windows

I would like to use my computer mic to talk with a friend. The problem is that the mic comes in *way* too quiet. On ubuntu, I have an option to set the mic volume to around 400%, and the quality is such that it actually sounds fine at this volume and I can refrain from yelling into the mic with my lips 1-inch away. Is there a way to do something similar on win-XP? I've been looking around for an hour but don't see a way. Perhaps some there is some software which can do this kind of thing out there...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look into Microphone Boost. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMMyrfZ08gg